# Confuse about the definition of yakimochi

Tags: definitions, english-to-japanese, comparative-linguistics

Is there any linguist said about yakimochi (焼餅) definition? I mean any research of that word?

Comment: Can you add some more details what are you confused with?

Comment: I would guess that the OP is interested to know how a word that means "jealousy" is also a  "rice cake". Did one meaning derive from the other, and why?

Comment: Please [edit](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/36530/edit) your question to make it more specific if it isn't answered by the linked question.